# Execute a procedure on an Advantage Database Server, from SQL Server 2008, with parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, remote-server, advantage-database-server

I currently use the statement:

```
select * from openquery(linkedserver, 'select a,b,c, from nameofview') rowset_1.
```

What I want to do is call a stored procedure on the Advantage Database Server, and pass parameters to it. The need for this is significant since the amount of data is growing at a fast pace.

Currently it takes over 15 minutes for a SQL report to present the data to the end user. I have been asked to make changes to the report that will just add to the time.

If I can pass the parameters to the procedure, and have the procedure reduce the amount of collected data, instead of having the report gather all of the data and then reduce it, would be great.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick: using SELECT * / omit the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) - select **only** what you **really** need!

Answer (score 2):

Using a stored procedure is similar to executing a query in Advantage,

```
select * from openquery(linkedserver, 'execute procedure nameofproc(p1, p2)') rowset_1
```

To define stored procedure, the database must be defined in a [data dictionary](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/master_advantage_data_dictionary.htm). The procedure may be implemented in DLL or [SQL script](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/master_create_procedure.htm)

A simpler way to improve performance may be just adding where clause to limit the amount of data returned by the server:

```
select * from openquery(linkedserver, 'select a,b,c, from nameofview WHERE ...') rowset_1
```